# php file_get_contents error when URL as variable

Tags: php, url, variables, file-get-contents

I'm struggling with weird problem with `file_get_contents()`.
First, the code loads XML from RSS address. Then `file_get_contents()` fetch HTML using a page address from the XML.

```
$url = 'http://www.moviejoy.com/rss/index.asp';
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load($url);

foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $link = $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $html = file_get_contents($link);
    print_r($html);
}
```

This code gives me an error says:

**Warning**: file_get_contents(http://www.moviejoy.com/qnam/view.asp?db=qna&num=2358) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/[ ... ]/index.php** on line **135**

But!
When I put the URL directly instead of $link, it works. Like this:
`$html = file_get_contents(http://www.moviejoy.com/qnam/view.asp?db=qna&num=2358);`

I have no idea what to do to fix this.
Help me, please!

Comment: Basic debugging: `var_dump($link);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in the rss source that the link is in this tag:

```
<link>
http://www.moviejoy.com/qnam/view.asp?db=qna&amp;num=2387               
</link>
```

so there's a new line before and after it. You can get the "clean" link by calling trim on it. So just add this:

```
$link = trim($link);
```

right after

```
$link = $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```